# Unable to change drop-down selection in Ruby Watir

Tags: ruby, selenium, watir

I am trying to select values one by one in a dropdown and having difficulty.

1. selenium-webdriver (4.0.3)
2. watir (7.0.0)
3. ChromeDriver 94.0.4606.81

The dropdown is md-select which on click displays a hidden div with 2 choices.

```
<md-select ng-if="vm.datas.length" ng-model="vm.activeData" ng-change="vm.refreshDash()" id="active-data-select" aria-label="data selector" class="ng-pristine ng-valid md-default-theme ng-empty ng-touched" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" role="button" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-invalid="false" aria-labelledby="active-data-select select_value_label_8" style="" aria-owns="select_listbox_10">
    <md-select-value class="md-select-value" id="select_value_label_8"><span><div class="md-text">My test data 1</div></span><span class="md-select-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span></md-select-value>
</md-select>

<div class="md-select-menu-container md-default-theme md-active md-clickable" aria-hidden="false" role="presentation" id="select_container_9" style="display: block; left: 507px; top: 8px; min-width: 336.891px; font-size: 20px;">  
    <md-select-menu role="presentation" class="_md md-default-theme" style="transform-origin: 152.445px 32px 0px;">
        <md-content role="listbox" tabindex="-1" aria-multiselectable="false" class="_md md-default-theme" id="select_listbox_10" aria-activedescendant="select_option_14">
            <!---->
                <md-option ng-repeat="data in ::vm.datas | orderBy:'name' track by $index" ng-value="data" value="[object Object]" ng-class="{'selected': data.name == vm.activeData.name }" tabindex="0" class="md-default-theme selected md-focused" role="option" id="select_option_14" selected="selected" aria-selected="true"><div class="md-text">My test data 1</div></md-option>
                <!---->
                <md-option ng-repeat="data in ::vm.datas | orderBy:'name' track by $index" ng-value="data" value="[object Object]" ng-class="{'selected': data.name == vm.activeData.name }" tabindex="0" class="md-default-theme" role="option" id="select_option_15"><div class="md-text">My test data 2</div></md-option>
            <!---->
        </md-content>
    </md-select-menu>
</div>
```

When I am trying to do the below to display the hidden div to select next value:

```
browser.element(id: 'active-data-select').click
```

I get the following error:
element located, but timed out after 30 seconds, waiting for #<Watir::HTMLElement: located: true; {:id=>"active-data-select"}> to be present

I have tried many different things, but not able to find a solution yet. Any ideas?

Thank you,
-Andrey

Comment: Located true means it finds the element, but for some reason, the is Displayed atom doesn't think that element should be able to be seen. Double check that no other elements exist on the page with that ID.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the JS library, might also double check if that's actually the right thing to click to get it to open.

Comment: Thank you for reply. The hidden div is on top of the select box. Is it possible that it prevents the click?

Comment: Yeah, if it's hidden, the driver won't click it. You need to click something that isn't hidden to show the hidden thing

Comment: Would they potentially need an event like mouseover?  I’ve seen controls where the thing you want to click only appears once the pointer is over that spot.

Comment: I tried to focus before clicking with no success. The hidden div is located on top of the select drop-down. So I have a feeling it prevents the click.

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain that clicking `select` element will solve your problem

`browser.element(id: 'active-data-select').fire_event :click`

will perform click even if element is obscured or not even on screen

You can also try

`browser.element(id: 'active-data-select').send_keys :enter`

or

`browser.element(id: 'active-data-select').send_keys [:down, :down, :enter]`

In your html it seems like div `select_container_9` is holding the select with options elements, so try

`browser.div(id: "select_container_9").select_list.options.first.select`

It seems like it's id is autogenerated so different locator should be used in case it works

But you should probably debug how many selects there are on page with
`browser.selects.count` then you can flash each `select` to pinpoint the one you are after with `browser.selects[x].flash` then count how many options are available in that select with `browser.selects[1].options.count` and then you can proceed with selecting the option you want with `browser.selects[1].options[1].select` and then improve locators